# Offset a label inside a polygon with mapbox-gl style?

Tags: cartography, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

Im trying to offset labels on the border of a polygon to the inside of the polygon in a mapbox-gl style. My data has a series of polygons with shared borders, and the labels on the borders need to be offset in to indicate which polygon is which.

The carto-css equivalent of the effect im looking for is `text-placement:line; text-dy:-5;`.

I would expect that `"symbol-placement": "line", "text-offset": [0,1]` in the `layout` properties would offset the labels in to the polygon, but it offsets the labels down, not inside.

[image: "text-offset": [0,1]]

Adding `"text-keep-upright": false` offsets the labels in the correct direction, but it makes the text upside down on the bottom edge of the polygons.

[image: "text-keep-upright": false]

Is there any way to offset the labels in, and keep them upright?

For the sake of completeness, here's a link to my style as it is now https://gist.github.com/JesseCrocker/17e11ccbe12c2b5393032f4585c13cdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe using "text-keep-upright": true is the way to go, the fact that that causes the labels to render on the wrong side of the line, I think is a bug see https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/2350

Comment: I agree that it seems like the right way to go, but im looking for something that works in practice, not in theory.